# How can I import data for my Django choices parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a model that has a character field, called 'country'.

I scraped the web and created a tuple (in another python file) with the countries that I would like the user to have the option of selecting. The tuple in the other file is exactly in the form that Django requires to, such as (("BR", "Brazil"), ("US", "The United States")).

Now, how can I import this tuple of countries in the 'choices' parameter (for example myfile.COUNTRIES)?

I simply don't know how to do it. How can I import this data in my Django project? Are there any best practices or recommendations for production?

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    COUNTRIES = ???

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")
    countries = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=False, null=True)
```

Here's the file containing the tuple:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

# Accessing website.
url = "..."
http_response = urlopen(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(http_response, "html.parser")

# Getting to the table.
table = html.find("table", {"class":"table table-hover"})

# Getting the table rows.
table_rows = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")

# Getting the country names.
countries = ()
for row in table_rows:
    td = row.find_all("td")[1]
    name = td.find("a").get_text()
    universities += (name, name)
```

Comment: Why is it in another file? Why can't you put it in this file?

Comment: Because there are more than 200 options. I scraped the data from the web and formatted it in a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

As you are scraping data, you need to store it somewhere to use in models. I would suggest to use database. You can create a model named Country:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And use it in your script like this:

```
for row in table_rows:
    td = row.find_all("td")[1]
    name = td.find("a").get_text()
    Country.objects.get_or_create(name=name, code=name)
```

For using the model in script, you can convert your script into a [custom django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/):

```
# your_app/management/commands/generate_countries.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Generate Countries'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = "..."
        http_response = urlopen(url)
        html = BeautifulSoup(http_response, "html.parser")
        table = html.find("table", {"class":"table table-hover"})
        table_rows = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")


        for row in table_rows:
            td = row.find_all("td")[1]
            name = td.find("a").get_text()
            Country.objects.get_or_create(name=name, code=name)
```

, so that you can use it like this: `python manage.py generate_countries`

And use country in your other models like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   ...
   countries = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

### Old Answer

Lets say your file is named `countries.py`, and in that file the tuple looks like this:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ("BR", "Brazil"),
    ("US", "The United States")
    ...
)
```

Now, lets say its in same folder as `models.py`, then you can simply import it like this:

```
from .countries import COUNTRIES
# if countries.py is in x module(folder with __init__.py file) then use
# from x.countires import COUNTRIES

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")
    countries = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=False, null=True)
```

Comment: I updated my question on how my file containing the tuple actually are. Could you take a look at it, please?